# How to ignore parts of a file when committing to Github?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project in Python, and some of my test cases include personal information. Currently, my testing workflow involves me just running each module as `__main__` and running through the specific test cases for which I am interested in seeing output. I expect this problem to also present when I move to a more traditional unit test methodology with a tests directory, etc.

Is there a way to ignore parts of a file when I add it to my Git commit? Basically, I've got ~200 lines of code, and then test lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_function(personal information)
```

I'd like to commit everything above the test lines, and leave the test lines out of my repository, where it could be available to others.

Again, I imagine this problem will present itself down the road as well, when I hard-code the personal information into my unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git add -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---patch) allows you to interactively select each chunk that you want to be added to staging.

---

Aside: This `-p`/`--patch` flag is also present in other daily-use commands like `checkout` when trying to “reset” a particular file (equivalent of the new `restore` command).